# Filtering elements from a ListBox via TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

Hi have created a listbox which is bound to list of machines. As the number of machines may increase dramatically I need to somehow filter by name. For that reason I have provided a TextBox where users can introduce a string to filter out.
I have thought to create another list which it will bind to the view, i.e, a second list just for visualization. However, I think there must be a cleaner way to do it.

```
<ListBox  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Visibility="{Binding MachinesPanelVisibility}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MachineRulesList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ItemSelectionIndex}" />

 <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="162" Text="Filter..." TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,44,18,13" />
```

**On the viewModel:**

```
public class BusinessRulesWizardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

public ObservableCollection<string> MachineRulesList
     {
       get { return _machineRulesList; }
       set
          {
            _machineRulesList = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("MachineRulesList");
          }
      }



 public BusinessRulesWizardViewModel(ISystemView systemViewManager, 
       IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
         _machineRulesList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _systemViewManager.GetMachines(page, pageSize).ToList().ForEach(
            item => _machineRulesList.Add(item)
         );
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using [CollectionViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) for filtering? Unfortunately this can be slow, because each time the whole view must be recreated, depending on your amount of items this can be to slow. Another good point to look at is this [AutoCompletionTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete%5Ftextbox.aspx), it is quite nice because it works asynchronously.

Comment: Please format your code properly in your question

Comment: Daniel, I cannot manage to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use ICollectionView interface to wrap your collection with `Filter` property set to a predicate that uses the text entered in the `TextBox`. Here is an example:

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Visibility="{Binding MachinesPanelVisibility}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding MachineRulesListView}" 
         SelectedIndex="{Binding ItemSelectionIndex}" />   
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="162" 
         Text="{Binding FilterText}" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,44,18,13" />
```

-

```
public class BusinessRulesWizardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

     public ObservableCollection<string> MachineRulesList
     {
       get { return _machineRulesList; }
       set
          {
            _machineRulesList = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("MachineRulesList");
          }
     }

     public string FilterText
     {
       get { return _filterText; }
       set
          {
            _filterText= value;
             OnPropertyChanged("FilterText");
            MachineRulesListView.Refresh();
          }
     }

     public ICollectionView MachineRulesListView { get; private set; }



    public BusinessRulesWizardViewModel(ISystemView systemViewManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
         _machineRulesList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MachineRulesListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_machineRulesList);
        MachineRulesListView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(r => ((string)r).Contains(FilterText));

        _systemViewManager.GetMachines(page, pageSize).ToList().ForEach(
            item => _machineRulesList.Add(item)
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got a compailer error saying that System.ComponentModel.IcollectionView does not contain a definition for 'Update'. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Manolete - Oh, sorry, it should be `Refresh`, not `Update`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Another problem that I've got is that  MachineRulesListView.Filter = new Predicate<string>(r => r.Contains(FilterText)) does not like it. It complains because cannot convert Predicate<string> to Predicate<object>. If I cast it, it compiles but it gives a runtime error...